# Javascript - sum of JSON Array by using the same date as key

Tags: javascript

I've 2 JSON arrays and 1 date to indicate the key, how to make it in one line per date basis and sum up the steel and concrete?

```
var a = ['Nov 1 2016','Nov 2 2016','Nov 3 2016','Nov 4 2016'];
var b = [{Date:'Nov 1 2016', steel:10.98},{Date:'Nov 3 2016', steel:5.67},{Date:'Nov 4 2016', steel:3.14}]
var c = [{Date:'Nov 1 2016', concrete:9.10},{Date:'Nov 2 2016', concrete:16.8},{Date:'Nov 4 2016', concrete:7.20}]

//output sum of steel and concrete
var x  =  [{Date:'Nov 1 2016', val:20.08},{Date:'Nov 2 2016', val:16.8},{Date:'Nov 3 2016', val:5.67},{Date:'Nov 4 2016', val:10.34}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is iterate over the dates array and for every date find the corresponding item in `b` and `c` (if not found provide a default item with a 0 value), and sum up their respective `steel` and `concrete` properties.

In other words, convert ([map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)) every date string into an object containing that date and the sum of `steel` and `concrete` for that date:

```
// dates is the `a` array, steelDays is the `b` array, concreteDays is the `c` array
const result = dates.map(date =>
  toDateAndValueObj(
    date,
    sumSteelAndConcrete(
      findByDate(steelDays, date),   
      findByDate(concreteDays, date) 
    )
  )
);
```

Where the functions would be

```
// converts a date and a value into an object containing that date and that value
const toDateAndValueObj = (date, val) => ({ date, val });

// takes two objects (or the objects with default values if passed undefined) and sums up their respective `steel` and `concrete` properties
const sumSteelAndConcrete = (s = { steel: 0 }, c = { concrete: 0 }) => s.steel + c.concrete;

// finds an item in the array who's Date property lexicographically equals the given date string
const findByDate = (arr, date) => arr.find(item => item.Date === date);
```

Note that I'm using string comparison for dates here for simplicity purposes. If you're using actual dates, you might need to construct [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects and use [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) to compare them:

```
const findByDate = (arr, date) => arr.find(item => new Date(item.Date).getTime() === new Date(date).getTime());
```

Full demo:

```js
const dates = ['Nov 1 2016','Nov 2 2016','Nov 3 2016','Nov 4 2016'];
const steelDays = [{Date:'Nov 1 2016', steel:10.98},{Date:'Nov 3 2016', steel:5.67},{Date:'Nov 4 2016', steel:3.14}];
const concreteDays = [{Date:'Nov 1 2016', concrete:9.10},{Date:'Nov 2 2016', concrete:16.8},{Date:'Nov 4 2016', concrete:7.20}];

const toDateAndValueObj = (date, val) => ({ date, val });
const sumSteelAndConcrete = (s = { steel: 0 }, c = { concrete: 0 }) => s.steel + c.concrete;
const findByDate = (arr, date) => arr.find(item => item.Date === date);

const result = dates.map(date =>
  toDateAndValueObj(
    date,
    sumSteelAndConcrete(
      findByDate(steelDays, date),
      findByDate(concreteDays, date)
    )
  )
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why I got this error when try to run in my code? **const sumSteelAndConcrete = (s = { steel: 0 }, c = { concrete: 0 }) => s.steel + c.concrete; \n SyntaxError: Unexpected token =**

Comment: that issue is most likely because your environment doesn't support default parameters (ES6). If you want the code to be ES5 and not use ES6 at all, you can just paste it into [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/) and use the transpilled version

Answer (score -1):

```js
var b = [{Date:'Nov 1 2016', steel:'10.98'},{Date:'Nov 3 2016', steel:'5.67'},{Date:'Nov 4 2016', steel:'3.14'}];
var c = [{Date:'Nov 1 2016', concrete:'9.10'},{Date:'Nov 2 2016', concrete:'16.8'},{Date:'Nov 4 2016', concrete:'7.20'}];
var obj = {};
for(var index in b){
  obj[b[index]['Date']] = b[index]['steel'];
}
for(index in c){
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(c[index]['Date'])){
    obj[c[index]['Date']] += c[index]['concrete'];
  }else{
    obj[c[index]['Date']] = c[index]['concrete'];
  }
}
var result = [];
for(var key in obj){
  result.push({Date:key, val:obj[key]});
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: in your example, on November 1 the value was concatenated, not added.